# How can bind jQuery to current document in Magento 2 When template load by ajax

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In Controller File

```
$block = $page->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct')
            ->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
        echo $block;
```

But when i append response in current Document then jQuery funtion not Working.

So what i do for append ajax response jQuery.

More Explain

by url request
http://localhost/magento2/category.html  load complete layout with filter

but when i send request to ajax on this http://localhost/magento2/category.html?color=23
only need product list and filter but when i get response jQuery not work.

Actually i want to run add to cart without page refresh this is working before call ajax but after when i click add to cart then page reload.

Comment: Standard way
`class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action { protected $resultPageFactory; public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory) { $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory; parent::__construct($context); } public function execute() { $resultPageFactory = $this->resultPageFactory->create(); return $resultPageFactory; } }`

Comment: Thanks For Reply,
But i want call layout using ajax and above solution is for access layout by url.

Comment: Ok @Prince Noted & Understood. Let me look out for that one

Comment: sorry don't get you. your `jQuery` is in main document or in `list.phtml`

Comment: Actually i want to run add to cart without page refresh this is working before call ajax but after when i click add to cart then page reload.

Comment: Please download https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp & check for `app\code\MagePal\GmailSmtpApp\view\adminhtml\templates\system\config\testbutton.phtml` files `$block->getAdminUrl()` function & it's AJAX file
`app\code\MagePal\GmailSmtpApp\Controller\Adminhtml\Test\Index.php`

Comment: @PrinceYadav where is your ajax code?